# Sequence of numbers representing probability distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

I have come across a tree of numbers that represents a probability distribution and was wondering if anybody can identify it.

$$
1 \\ 1\;\;\; 1 \\ 1\;\;\; 3\;\;\; 1 \\ 1\;\;\; 6\;\;\; 7\;\;\; 1 \\ 1\;\;\; 10\;\; 25\;\; 15\;\;\; 1\\ 1\;\;\; 15\;\;\; 65\;\;\; 90 \;\;\; 31\;\;\; 1\\ 1\;\;\; 21\;\;\; 140\;\;\; 350\;\;\; 301\;\;\; 63\;\;\; 1 \\ \vdots
$$

The distribution appears skewed to the right looking at the numbers. The sequence for the left and right second diagonals are simple (i.e. left 2nd diagonal is +n-1 where n is row number starting with unity).

If it at all helps, this sequence comes from the differential operator that I have been studying

$$
T_n(x) = \left(x\partial_x \right)^n
$$

by expanding out the operator.

Comment: Sum the numbers horizontally & search OEIS http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C5%2C15%2C52&sort=&language=english&go=Search ... They are the Bell numbers ... your grid is a known grading of them ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the "Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences" ([oeis.org](http://oeis.org)). You can type in your numbers, and it will try to match it up.

This triangle gives the Stirling numbers of 2nd kind, $S(n,n-k+1)$.